# Test database connection in php without username & password

Tags: php, mysqli

There are some [nice php database connection tests](https://gist.github.com/chales/11359952#gistcomment-2727869) around, but they all seem to require a username & password. How would one confirm (using php and presumably mysqli) that a database server is up and *would* accept connections should one be attempted with a correct username & password, but report some details on the failure if the server was down or timed out or what not.

Comment: Look for a difference in the error message. If the server is offline you'll get a different error message when trying to connect than you will if it's there but it doesn't recognise the credentials. Or you could just try and telnet to the port.

Comment: I have to say this is a rather strange requirement. Credentials are set up by the system administrator so if your access is denied then it means the server is not reachable from your POV.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would use the code 1045 to see if you can connect. This error code indicates that the credentials are incorrect. If the server responds with that code then it means it is reachable.

```
<?php

$reachable = false;

mysqli_report(MYSQLI_REPORT_ERROR | MYSQLI_REPORT_STRICT);
try {
    $mysqli = new mysqli('localhost', 'some invalid user', 'wrong password');
} catch (mysqli_sql_exception $e) {
    if (1045 === $e->getCode()) {
        $reachable = true;
    }
}

var_dump($reachable);
?>
```